# Magento 2 "All Customers" page does not work

Tags: magento2, customer

[image]

Why doesn't load this page?
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the page and check whether any js is loading properly if not loading properly then delete the pub folders and run the below code from the root folder

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I did it but doesnt work. The error is this
> Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.
http://magento.dev/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js


Can you help me ?

Comment: It is due to the knockout js kindly refer this URL http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.knockoutjs/10340

Comment: but this it's a problem of magento. I didn't overwrite magento code. I only install magento 2 and add a user for test. But when I open Customer and All Customer in the admin panel the page doesnt work. Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

The right solution is to download the source from magento web page not from github.

Answer (score 0):

Reindex customer grid.

```
php bin/magento indexer/reindex customer_grid
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's Magento 2.3 and higher try:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset customer_grid
php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```

It might work for lower versions but I haven't tried it

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing it on your local, in my case it was showing an error instead of just being blank as in dev